# ASP.NET Windows Authentication Mode, IIS7 and custom error pages - how?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I have a bunch of users.  If they are not in a specific role I don't want them to have access to the site.  This is straightforward using stock .NET membership/roles providers, setting the Authentication mode to Windows and setting up a few access rules and an intercept at the end of a request, to redirect to a custom 401 error page - with Cassini.

Step forward IIS7 and integrated pipelining, just how is this possible when deploying my site to a Webserver using this version of IIS and this mode of operation? Should I revert to a Classic application pool, or is that defeating the purpose of having more control over  requests in the pipeline.

Comment: What issues are you having with this now? Membership and role providers still work in IIS7.

Comment: Yes they do. My issue is that, although there appears to be provision for the whole gamut of Http errors (e.g. 401 through to 500) and the ability to set up custom errors.  Actually providing a non-static, master page driven, error page (which works on Cassini) is proving seemingly 'impossible' to configure using IIS7 and Integrated mode.

Comment: edit to convey that nothing is impossible

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very basic, but have you tried it? This goes in the Web.config file.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx">
    </customErrors>
```

Also, I sometimes put the following code in the Application_Error event in the Global file to log an Exception:

```
    ' Fires when an error occurs
    ' Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

    Dim ErrorDescription As String = Server.GetLastError.ToString

    ' Log the Error to Event Log
    'Creation of event log if it does not exist  
    Dim EventLogName As String
    EventLogName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ApplicationLog").ToString()

    If (Not EventLog.SourceExists(EventLogName)) Then
      EventLog.CreateEventSource(EventLogName, EventLogName)
    End If

    ' Inserting into event log
    Dim Log As New EventLog()
    Log.Source = EventLogName
    Log.WriteEntry(ErrorDescription, EventLogEntryType.Error)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work.  Custom errors for 401.2 and 401.3 errors are outside of the realm of being handled by ASP.NET. As I understand it, they are handled by IIS7 before ASP.NET can get its hands on the invalid request, and you have to dance like the funky chicken to display a graceful error message.